# i18n is changing the output of Ajax call

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have a datepicker function that was working pefectly well until I internationalized my application. But now, it's not working anymore. Here is my Ajax function :

```
$datepicker.change(function(){              
   currentDate = $datepicker.datepicker( "getDate" );
   dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", currentDate);
   console.log("My dateString is: "+dateString);
```

Here my console is showing the right date

```
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "movements/getTO/",
          data: {"date":dateString},
        }).done(function(data) {
          $("#resultTO").html(data[0])
          $("#resultQty").html(data[1])
        });
   });
```

with this controller function :

```
def getTO
    selected_date = Date.parse(params[:date])
    new_html_to_return1 = Movement.where(:movement_date =>selected_date, :user => current_user.email).sum("turnover")
    new_html_to_return2 = Movement.where(:movement_date =>selected_date, :user => current_user.email).sum("quantity")
    @table = [new_html_to_return1, new_html_to_return2]
    render :json => @table
end
```

My routes.rb :

```
post "movements/getTO"
scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    resources :movements
    (...)
end
match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"), constraints: lambda { |req| !req.path.starts_with? "/#{I18n.default_locale}/" }
match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

At this point, my datepicker was having a route trouble. So I added in routes.rb

```
match 'movements/getTO', to: redirect("movements/getTO")
```

But that's not right because now I have as output : < and !. Incredible for sums isn't it ???